# Access element in list and replace value based on condition

Tags: python

I'm having a quick question with the following while loop and if condition

```
import random
CAR = 'c'
c = CAR
GOAT = 'g'

PICK = "*"
UNKNOWN = "?"

game_state = ['?', '?', '?', '?', '*']
door_contents = ['g', 'g', 'g', 'c', 'g']
```

I need the following result.

```
game_state = ['g', 'g', 'g', '?', '*']
```

Pretty much, whenever the index value of game_state[index] = PICK or door_contents[index] = CAR, then leave it alone, otherwise change the value of game_state[index] = GOAT

I have the following function but its not giving me the correct value.

```
def revealGoats(game_state, door_contents):
    count = 0
    to_open = len(door_contents) - 2

    while count <= to_open:
        index = int(random.choice(range(len(door_contents))))
        if ((door_contents[index] != CAR) | (game_state[index] != PICK)) & (game_state[index] != GOAT):
            game_state[index] = GOAT
        count += 1

    return game_state
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What *specifically* is this code doing wrong?

Comment: What if one list has a different size than the other?

Comment: The size of both list will always be the same for this exercise.

Comment: @ScottHunter It's not accessing the correct elements and replacing the values.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps:

```
import random

CAR = "c"
c = CAR
GOAT = "g"

PICK = "*"
UNKNOWN = "?"


def revealGoats(game_state, door_contents):
    count = 0
    to_open = len(door_contents) - 2

    while count <= to_open:
        index = int(random.choice(range(len(door_contents))))
        if ((door_contents[index] != CAR) | (game_state[index] != PICK)) & (
            game_state[index] != GOAT
        ):
            game_state[index] = GOAT
        count += 1

    return game_state


gs = ["?", "?", "?", "?", "*"]
dc = ["g", "g", "g", "c", "g"]

result = None
while result != ["g", "g", "g", "?", "*"]:
    result = revealGoats(gs.copy(), dc.copy())
    print(result)
```

Comment: Hi - thanks. But I don't think the "while result != ["g", "g", "g", "?", "*"]" will work since both list will be randomly generated. So the c and * will be in different positions every time.

Comment: I just did that as a test case from the result you said you needed in the question. If there is an problem I overlooked I can help you out with that further, misunderstanding on my part.